# Mathematical journal for an undergraduate

Tags: reference-request

I want to make someone a present by subscribing for him to a mathematical journal. (It should appear every month or every two months). The contents should be comprehensible to an undergraduate in mathematics, and be about a broad selection of topics (for example not only analysis).

I expect the content to be something like proposing interesting problems and then giving solutions with some references for further study.
Are there some famous journals you could suggest me?

Comment: Have you seen some editions of the American Math Monthly? Not any specific field, a lot of material that is accessible to undergrads, and at the back there's a problems section.

Comment: @RagibZaman I have not much experience with mathematical journals but I will make sure to take a look at the one you refered

Comment: College Math Journal and Math Magazine are among some one might want to look at too. (I would have suggested AMM too, but it is already up there.)

Comment: I see my answer agrees with these comments. The time-delay of answer writing - so it goes.

Comment: Although it only comes out 3 times a year, I would recommend looking at The Mathematical Gazette http://www.m-a.org.uk/jsp/index.jsp?lnk=620 Each issue contains a large number of short articles (far more than CMJ or MM), many of which are within the level of someone whose only background is a standard 3-semester calculus sequence.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the three best possibilities here are the American Mathematical Monthly, Mathematics Magazine, or the College Mathematics Journal.

A table of contents and some info on AMM can be found [here](http://www.maa.org/pubs/monthly.html).

Similarly for MM [here](http://www.maa.org/pubs/mathmag.html). And the CMJ [here](http://www.maa.org/pubs/cmj.html).

Of the three, I'd estimate the CMJ to be the most approachable. But a large idea of it is aimed at educators of upper high school or beginning to mid undergraduate math. AMM and MM are both approachable, but will also have some things which likely aren't familiar to an undergrad. But every article is written in an incredibly approachable way.

All three have problem and answer sections as well, with the general difficulty being AMM > MM > CMJ (least difficult). Nonetheless, it would be rare for an undergrad to be able to do all the problems every month. Let me emphasize - really rare.

Perhaps the most important aspect is that the math articles and papers, which I consider to be very real, are not terse. The articles are written to be approachable and dense, often with large doses of humor. I used to read the AMM and the MM all the time, and I enjoyed that part of my undergraduate days. I still write up a solution to a problem every now and then, too.

Comment: Each of MM and CMJ appear 5 times a year, on alternating months (except summer), making a combined subscription option attractive.

Answer (score 9):

Have you considered the *Mathematical Intelligencer*? The Mathematical Intelligencer publishes articles about mathematics, about mathematicians, and about the history and culture of mathematics. It informs and entertains a broad audience of mathematicians and the wider intellectual community. The Mathematical Intelligencer welcomes expository articles on all kinds of mathematics and interdisciplinary trends, and articles that portray the diversity of mathematical communities and mathematical thought. Humor is welcome, as are puzzles, poetry, fiction, and of course art. Forthcoming issues will feature emergent mathematical communities around the world, new interdisciplinary trends, and relations between mathematics and other areas of culture. Makes a great reading!!

Comment: Dear @NickyHekster, may I ask what is the (average) required background to read the *Mathematical Intelligencer*?

Comment: Just a keen interest in math. Undergrad level is OK, but some papers can even be appreciated by high school students.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Would you mind telling me what are (normally) the areas of mathematics the articles deal with?

Comment: @Dal, why don't you take a look at http://www.springer.com/mathematics/journal/283 and browse "Popular content within this publication". Perhaps your nearest library at the math faculty has the journal. Normally it covers a wide range of topics.

Answer (score 3):

The MAA journal [*Math Horizons*,](http://www.maa.org/publications/periodicals/math-horizons) which comes out four times a year, is explicitly geared toward undergraduates.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider the periodical Resonance (http://www.ias.ac.in/Journals/Resonance_%E2%80%93_Journal_of_Science_Education/).

Answer (score 0):

Some online highschool journals:

- https://cms.math.ca/crux/
- http://lbcone.ust.hk/hkustpub/list.php?id=53
- https://www.komal.hu/info/bemutatkozas.e.shtml